# Construct a dependent type out of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, singleton

I want to write a library in Haskell for Galois fields. A Galois field is defined by its irreducible polynomial. Galois field elements can only be added if they have the same Galois field. I want to lift the polynomial into the type of my Galois field, so that for example a Galois field with the polynomial [1, 2, 3] has a different type than a Galois Field with the polynomial [2, 0, 1]. This way i could assure that only Galois field elements with the same Galois field can be added. Is this possible?

My polynomial data type looks like this:

```
newtype Polynomial a = Polynomial [a]
```

My Galois field data type look like this:

```
data GF irr a = GF {
    irreducible :: irr
  , q :: PrimePower
}
```

So i want a constructor that takes a polynomial (for example `(Polynomial [2, 0, 1])`) and gives me a Galois field of the type `GF (Polynomial Int) ([2, 0, 1])`.
I know that `[2, 0, 1]` is not a valid type but i saw that with [Data.Singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.6) it is possible to create types like

```
(SCons STrue (SCons SFalse SNil))
```

for `[True, False]`, but i do not know how to construct types likes these from my list `[2, 0, 1]` and how the constructor would look like.

Comment: With `DataKinds` it is possible to use lists at the type level.  With `GHC.TypeLits` you can use naturals at the type level.  What you can't do is proper dependent types, in which you construct a type based on a value you, say, got from the user (not without specifying an inductive scheme to get there, at least).

Comment: Incidentally, there's this library for Galois Fields in Hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/galois-field

Answer (score 5):

As Luke already commented, `[2, 0, 1]` *is* actually a valid type.

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds -XPolyKinds 
Prelude> data A x = A deriving Show
Prelude> A :: A [2,0,1]
A
```

where the number literals are actually type-level [`Nat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Nat) literals, and `[...]` is a *lifted* version of the list value-constructor to the type kind. This can be made explicit by writing it with “prime-quote syntax”

```
Prelude> A :: A '[2, 0, 1]
A
```

...so, this task is actually pretty trivial. You can just use

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)

newtype Polynomial a = Polynomial [a]

data GF (irr :: Polynomial Nat) = GF {q :: PrimePower}
```

As also said by Luke, keep in mind though that type-level calculations don't work as well as they do in full dependently-typed languages. If you really want to do proof stuff with this, you should consider switching to Idris, Agda or Coq.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However im not quite sure how to construct a Galois field of the type `Polynomial Nat`. I tried it by using `GF (PrimePower 2 3) :: (Polynomial '[1, 2, 3])`, but i get the error _Expected a type, but ‘'[1, 2, 3]’ has kind ‘[Nat]’_. Besides, when i add two Galois field elements, i add their polynomials modulo the irreducible polynomial of their common Galois field. So i need to convert the type of GF to a polynomial. I know i can convert `Nat` to a number by using `natVal`, but how can i convert `Polynomial Nat` to, for example, `Polynomial [1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the "lifted" value will be used merely as a tag. For cases in which we only want it to work as a tag, but it's difficult to lift the required value to the type level with `DataKinds`, a possible alternative consists in attaching to the value a "ghostly" type tag conjured by means of a polymorphic incantation. Consider this helper module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Named (Named,forgetName,name) where

newtype Named n a = Named a -- don't export the constructor

forgetName :: Named n a -> a
forgetName (Named a) = a

name :: a -> ( forall name. Named name a -> r ) -> r
name x f = f ( Named x ) -- inside the callback, "x" has a "name" type tag attached
```

And this other module which depends on it:

```
module GF (Polynomial(..),GF,stuff,makeGF,addGF) where

import Named

newtype Polynomial a = Polynomial [a]

data GF a = GF { -- dont' export the constructor
    _stuff :: Int -- don't export the bare field
}

stuff :: GF a -> Int
stuff (GF x) = x

makeGF :: Named ghost (Polynomial Int) -> Int -> GF ghost
makeGF _ = GF 

addGF :: Named ghost (Polynomial Int) -> GF ghost -> GF ghost -> GF ghost
addGF _ x1 x2 = GF (stuff x1 + stuff x2)
```

I would be impossible for *clients* of this module to sum two `GF` values with different ghostly tags. Their only way of creating ghostly tags is through `name`, and they don't have the means of re-tagging either the `Named` values or the `GF` ones—we carefully hid constructors and bare fields to prevent that. So this would compile:

```
module Main where

import Named
import GF

main :: IO ()
main = print $
    name (Polynomial [2::Int,3,4]) $ \ghost ->
      let x1 = makeGF ghost 3
          x2 = makeGF ghost 4
       in stuff (addGF ghost x1 x2)
```

But this wouldn't:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $
    name (Polynomial [2::Int,3,4]) $ \ghost1 ->
        name (Polynomial [3::Int]) $ \ghost2 ->
          let x1 = makeGF ghost1 3
              x2 = makeGF ghost2 4
           in stuff (addGF ghost1 x1 x2)
```

Comment: For a detailed explanation of this technique see the paper "Ghosts of Departed Proofs" https://kataskeue.com/gdp.pdf and these posts: https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2019-08-09-who-authorized-these-ghosts.html https://chrisdone.com/posts/ghost-of-departed-proofs-conveniences/

Comment: The "gdp" package implements the "Named" machinery http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gdp